# How do you create a cumulative sales graph in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

The bar and line charts in Power BI allow you to graph total sales by month.  Example
Jan Sales $100
Feb Sales $200
Mar Sales $150

I am looking for a way to graph those same numbers but show a cumulative sales total to show total revenue for the year.  Essentially, I would like the total for the current bar added to the sum of all bars to the left of it.  Example from above would look like this:
Jan Sales $100
Feb Sales $100+$200= $300
Mar Sales $300+$150= $450

This would allow you to see total sales volume over the year.  Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Comment: You will need to create a new column (Cumulative Sales) and then use it in your chart.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and clearest visual to achieve this would be the "Waterfall chart", which would look like this:

[image: Power BI Waterfall chart example]

Comment: Thanks I found that as well.  The limitation of that solution is that you can not compare year over year.  I have tried the following solution and got what I was looking for.  Not sure it is the best solution.  Still trying to clean things up.  I created a table from my original query using the create table feature ->  Totals = SUMMARIZE(query1
      , Query1[Show Year]
      , Query1[Num_Weeks_Out]
      , "Week Registrations", SUM(Query1[Registrations]) , "Week Reg Amount", SUM(Query1[BASE_TOTAL_AMOUNT])
      )

Comment: I also then created a column in that new table with the following ->  Total Reg Amount = SUMX(FILTER(query1, (query1[show year] = 'Totals'[Show Year] && query1[Num_Weeks_Out] <= 'Totals'[Num_Weeks_Out])),Query1[BASE_TOTAL_AMOUNT])   That allowed me to use a line chart or bar chart to compare the amounts year over year.